How do I write robots.txt with specific parameters?
I want Google to ignore(disallow) URLs like this:

(Disallow) http://example.com/*/?page=2

But if the URL contains "article",
I don't want to exclude it (allow) URLs like this:

(Allow) http://example.com/article/?page=2
(Allow) http://example.com/*/article/?page=2

How do I do so with robots.txt?
User-Agent: *

Disallow: /?page=*

Allow: /article/?page=*


To configure your robots.txt file to disallow URLs like http://example.com/*/?page=2 but allow URLs containing article, you'll need to carefully structure your rules. Unfortunately, the robots.txt standard doesn't support wildcards at the beginning of a rule (like /*/) or regular expressions. However, you can achieve the intended behavior with specific patterns.
Here’s a robots.txt file that might help:
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*?page=
Allow: /*/article/?page=
Allow: /article/?page=

Explanation:
Disallow: /*?page=
This blocks any URL that contains ?page=, regardless of its position.
Allow: /*/article/?page=
This explicitly allows URLs where article appears in the path before ?page=. For example, http://example.com/something/article/?page=2.
Allow: /article/?page=
This explicitly allows URLs that start with /article/ and contain ?page=. For example, http://example.com/article/?page=2.
Notes:
Rules in robots.txt are read in order. More specific Allow rules can override broader Disallow rules.
Be sure to test your robots.txt file using Google Search Console's Robots Testing Tool to verify it behaves as expected.
The above solution works for most user-agents that adhere to the robots.txt standard. For finer control, consider using meta tags (noindex) or HTTP headers on specific pages.

Thank you for your quick answer.
Disallow: /*?page=
Allow: /*/article/?page=
Allow: /article/?page=
I added the above to robots.txt and tested the operation with logeix's "Robots.txt Testing Tool," but the URL with article is blocked.

some robots.txt testing tools or crawlers might not handle overlapping Allow and Disallow rules exactly as intended, especially with the wildcard syntax. Test directly with Google’s Robots.txt Tester in Google Search Console to confirm crawler behavior.
Test this.
User-Agent: *
Allow: //article/?page=
Allow: /article/?page=
Disallow: /?page=
